# What to try Ether as CLI options on test network to learn

Tags: wallets, ether, testing, cli

I'm pretty new for Ether, i have invest a little in it, but now i think its will be fun to learn more about it.

i want to running linux to try out a Ether CLI node so i can developer up to it over REST, first i ofc want the test network to test on before live.

So i will ask you guys and grils about you know somthing about this, and where i shut starting to learn about it?

My idea its ofc to host my own wallet, and later build a applicaion on Ether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geth`.

Ubuntu installation instructions: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu

Launch in testnet: `geth --fast --rpc --testnet`

And you can interact with `geth` via `curl` (See Ethereum JSON RPC API documentation for examples)

Also you need to generate some testnet ethers for yourself first (takes ~1 hour to get first ethers): `geth --fast --rpc --testnet --mine`

Comment: Thanks a lot, and where its my wallet data storge? i need a backup progress if somthing go wrong in live-mode :)

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore